# APNS - Getting device token

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am going to implement push notifications in my app with the AppNotify service. To finish setting that service up I need to get my device token. I have tried using the code from Apple's docs. On the simulator I get an error (expected of course). On my device I do not get an error, but I do not get the token either. Neither delegate method is called. Here is the code (first bit goes in applicationDidFinishLaunching):

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
//const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];
//self.registered = YES;
//[self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes]; // custom method
NSLog(@"Success");
NSLog(@"Token = %@", devToken);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once, you must know that remote notifications doesn't work on simulator.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

add the following method as well:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
       for (id key in userInfo)
       {
             NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
        }    
}
```

If you have written the right code (as you show) one of the above 3 methods (the 2 you have written and the one i have above) gets called. If you don't get any error on the device then wait for some time (ideally 10 seconds but it maybe take longer as well) for the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method to get called. Regards.